# loading xml file to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert data from Xml file using a stored procedure, stored procedure as below :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xmlreadtest
@xmldoc xml
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Page (KeyId)
    SELECT [Key].value('@Id[1]', 'VARCHAR (100)') 
    FROM   @xmldoc.nodes('//Page/Key') AS TEMPTABLE([Key])

END
```

And Visual Basic calling the procedure :

```
Function ModfiyData()

    Dim xmldocM As New XmlDocument
    xmldocM.Load("C:\20170326.66.xml")
    Dim SQLComm As New SqlCommand
    Dim dbconn As New SqlConnection(con)
    dbconn.Open()
    SQLComm.Connection = dbconn
    SQLComm.CommandText = "xmlreadtest"
    SQLComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xmldoc", xmldocM)
    SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbconn.Close()

End Function
```

When i run the application it give error:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Xml.XmlDocument to a known managed provider native type.

Any idea how can i solve this issue..
i am using vb 2015 and sql database file.

Comment: I'd try to return it as varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Casting `XmlDocument` to `SqlXML`

```
Dim xmldocM As New XmlDocument
xmldocM.Load("C:\20170326.66.xml")

Dim sw as new StringWriter()
Dim xw as new XmlTextWriter(sw)
xmldocM.WriteTo(xw)
Dim  transactionXml as  new StringReader(sw.ToString())
Dim xmlReader AS new XmlTextReader(transactionXml)
Dim XmlParamValue as new SqlXml(xmlReader) 

Dim SQLComm As New SqlCommand
Dim dbconn As New SqlConnection(con)
dbconn.Open()
SQLComm.Connection = dbconn
SQLComm.CommandText = "xmlreadtest"
SQLComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xmldoc", XmlParamValue )
SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
dbconn.Close()
```

Comment: Yes It Worked .. Thanks.